# Alterar dominio projeto android

Tags: android, android-studio

Preciso alterar o domínio do meu projeto android.

Exemplo:

Quando criei o projeto coloquei um dominio fictício: **br.com.dominio-x**

Depois quando o projeto evoluiu, eu registrei um domínio válido: **br.com.dominio-y**

Preciso fazer essa alteração e não sei qual o procedimento mais recomendável.

obs: 
Eu encontrei vários procedimentos na internet, como: utilizar Refactor, Alterar o Gradle, fazer as duas coisas ou só uma. Enfim vários exemplos.

Gostaria de saber qual a maneira mais recomendada pois o aplicativo está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Troque no Graddle e no Androidmanifest, nem é necessário mudar no manifest, mas se quiser deixar tudo ajeitadinho hehe troque no manifest tmb..

Comment: Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/2570426

Comment: @Matheus "nem é necessário mudar no manifest," isso não é verdade, veja https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_package_name. Lá é dito o seguinte: *"However, if you want to change your package name, be aware that the package name (as defined by your project directory structure) should always match the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file"*

Comment: @ramaral na empresa onde trabalho, tive que unificar todo o código do aplicativo para gerar outros aplicativos, e para fazer isto apenas altero o id do grandle.

Comment: @Matheus Acredito, apenas mencionei o que é dito na documentação. Retiro a parte " isso não é verdade".

Comment: @ramaral haha que isso, talvez eu esteja errado tambem kk se estiver iremos descobrir daqui um tempo quando as bombas explodir =)

Comment: @Matheus Veja o último paragrafo com o título "One more thing to know:". Talvez seja por isso que você está certo. De qualquer forma a documentação é ambígua(algo que eu já sei mas que às vezes esqueço).

Comment: @ramaral tranquilo vou dar uma olhada sim, agradeço.

Comment: Outro aspecto que se deve ter em conta é o que é dito no primeiro paragrafo a respeito à alteração do `applicationId ` no *build.gradle*: *"... once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tradução e adaptação [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package/29092698#29092698) para esta pergunta sobre: [*Android Studio Rename Package*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package).

---

Por exemplo, para alterar de `br.com.dominio-x` para `br.com.dominio-y`, então faça:

1. No Painel do Projeto, canto lateral esquerdo da tela, clique no ícone de configurações ( [image: Gears icon] )
2. Desmarque/De-selecione a opção *Compact Empty Middle Packages*:

[image: Compact Empty Middle Packages]

3. Agora seu pacote será dividido em diretórios individuais.
4. Selecione individualmente cada diretório que deseja renomear:

   - Clique no botão direito do mouse
   - Selecione <kbd>Refactor</kbd>
   - Clique em <kbd>Rename</kbd>
   - Na caixa de diálogo, clique em <kbd>Rename Package</kbd> em vez de <kbd>Rename Directory</kbd>
   - Insira o novo nome e clique em <kbd>Refactor</kbd>
   - Clique em <kbd>Do Refactor</kbd> na janela abaixo
   - Aguarde alguns minutos enquanto o Android Studio atualize todas alterações.
   - *Nota: Ao renomear com o Android Studio, pode dar um aviso. Neste caso clique em <kbd>Rename All</kbd>

[image]

5. Agora abra seu ***Gradle Build File*** (`build.gradle` - Que encontra-se em `app` ou `mobile`). Atualize o `applicationId` para o novo nome do pacote e clique em <kbd>Sync</kbd> no Gradle, caso não seja atualizado automaticamente.

[image: Refactor Directories]

6. ***Pronto!*** De qualquer forma, o Android Studio precisaria tornar esse processo mais simples.

Comment: Considero útil ter a resposta em português. +1 pelo trabalho de tradução.